# Django running a javascript function imported from parent, called by the child

Tags: javascript, django, inheritance

I have a javascript file in an outside folder under static. My index.html is not running the javascript function that was imported from base.html.

**File path:**

```
-- project
   -- app
      -- templates
         -- app name
            -- index.html
   -- src
   -- static
      -- hello_world.js
   -- templates
      -- base.html
```

**View page source from browser**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>

  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>

    <script type='text/javascript' src="/static/hello_world.js"></script>
  </head> 

  <body>

<div id="navigation">
<table border=0 cellpadding=7>
<tr>
    <td><a href="/game">Home</a></td>

      <td><a href="/game/registration">Register</a></td>
      <td><a href="/game/login">Login</a></td>

</tr>
</table>
</div>


<div id="content">

    <h2> Welcome to WAM's board 2 player board games! </h2>
    <canvas onload="entryPoint();" id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Base.html**

```
{% block doctype %}<!DOCTYPE HTML> {% endblock %}
<html>
{% block head %}
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
{% load staticfiles %}
    <script type='text/javascript' src="{% static "hello_world.js" %}"></script>
  </head> 
{% endblock %}
  <body>
{% block navbar %}
<div id="navigation">
<table border=0 cellpadding=7>
<tr>
    <td><a href="/game">Home</a></td>
{% if user_logged_in %}
      <td><a href="/game/upload">Upload</a></td>
      <td><a href="/game/challenge_user">Challenge User</a></td>
      <td><a href="/game/logout">Logout</a> of {{ user_name }}</td>
{% else %}
      <td><a href="/game/registration">Register</a></td>
      <td><a href="/game/login">Login</a></td>
{% endif %}
</tr>
</table>
</div>

{% endblock %}
<div id="content">
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block navbar %}{{ block.super }}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
    <h2> Welcome to WAM's board 2 player board games! </h2>
    <canvas onload="entryPoint();" id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Are you using Django's built-in development web server or a production server? Do you have `DEBUG=True` or `False` in your `settings.py`?

Comment: I am on my running it on my local machine. 'DEBUG=True'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)) # already present in newest django versions
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

in your settings.py, or simply put your static files inside static folders inside app folders

Comment: This worked. I know the script is found because I can see it in this app called firebug in the script section. The script its self is not working but at least its found. I will talk with my group partner about the js code its self.